# [META] Are we being merged into the other stack exchange brew site?

Tags: meta, stackexchange2.0

Are we just being added to stack exchange or are we being merged with the new [stack exchange brew site](http://homebrew.stackexchange.com) that opened yesterday?

Answer (score 1):

The latter.

But we will be keeping our questions, answers, users, and reputation.

Essentially, this will make sure that the community doesn't become segmented, and will allow the current site and community to harness the continued power of StackExchange (SE), while the new Area51 site (homebrew.stackexchange.com) benefits from what we've built over the past year.

Details:

- We are turning over the ownership, database, and content of the site, brewadvice.com, to the Stack Exchange community. It will be as if the site was created through Area 51.
- SE will import the questions, answers, comments, voting, and the users (and their credentials) to a Stack Exchange 2.0 site.
- SE will forgo the remainder of the private beta so there is no disruption of service for our users. The site will run as a public beta for about 90 days, or until the site is ready to graduate as a full site.
- The site will have no administrator and no private ownership. We will not be able to place ads or have any sort of administrative access to the site.
- SE will appoint a few of us as Moderators under the Moderator Pro Tem program but at some point the community will have to elect their own Moderators. We are, of course, free to participate in those elections.
- The sites URL is currently http://homebrew.stackexchange.com. SE can set up a permanent redirect from brewadvice.com to homebrew.stackexchange.com. That will provide a seamless user experience for our users.
- The selection of a "permanent name" for the site is generally up to the users. The decision of which sites get their own domain name and which will use the Stack Exchange subdomain is in a bit of a transition right now. SE would be happy to dub the site "brewadvice.com" but, ultimately, it is up to the community and whatever criteria we settle on.

Comment: Don't forget the features like official "Meta" section and chat! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Merger. So everyone needs to play nice with the new kids :)

Comment: But I don't like making new friends!

Comment: @brewchez it's ok, with your rep, you don't have to be nice.

Comment: @[everyone else] - kidding about that last comment.

Answer (score 0):

So, what does that mean for users; I have some rep on this site, and already some on the new site...is all that getting merged, too?

Comment: That's a great question to which I don't know the answer. Let me try and find out.

Comment: We'll have to manually merge those accounts.  Send an email to team@stackexchange.com once we've merged the sites and we can merge your two accounts.